# run a script to rename several words in a txt file

Tags: string, batch-file, rename, words

I need your help. 
I have a txt file in a directory (folder) and need to run a script to rename several words, eg.

where LX4XAB to LX4xab 
and where is XS3X44 to Xs3x44 
and another word

until the end save the file with another name.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (input1.txt) do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:LX4XAB=LX4xab!"
        set "line=!line:XS3X44=Xs3x44!"
        echo(!line!
)) > newfile.txt
```

**Revision 1**

Here is how you can do it with multiple files and doing the naming the way you asked for.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d C:\Temp
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
  echo %%~nxa|Find /i "_new">nul
  if errorlevel 1 (
    (for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (%%a) do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:LX4XAB=LX4xab!"
        set "line=!line:XS3X44=Xs3x44!"
        echo(!line!
    )) > %%~na_new.txt
  ) 
  echo %%~nxa|Find /i "_new">nul
  if errorlevel 1 ren %%~nxa %%~na.old
)
```

Comment: As `for` skips blank lines then this code is always true: `if not "%%f"==""` and can be removed, right?

Comment: yep. I forgot about `for` skipping blank lines. Edited.

Comment: I appreciate the help Matt. But I still want to refine my batch.

1-not be only a file, but all that exist in the directory

2-write the new with original file name+_new and change original file the extension to *.Old

can someone help me to do this? Thank you.