# change word inside multi TXT and save same name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to change a word "EDI" to "INO" inside all the TXT files in the folder but save the same name the folder.

inside folderA have xyzfile01_xyx.txt, xyzfile02_xyz.txt ... to xyzfile50_xyz.txt

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%txtfile%) do (
   set newline=%%a
   set newline=!newline:EDI=INO!
)
```

Comment: There are many existing questions about how to loop through files in a folder. Please do some research. `[batch-file] loop files in folder` is a search expression that should be useful.

Comment: Excuse. But I do not understand anything. You can not help me.

Comment: [Run a script to rename several workds in a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21932829/62576)

Comment: You asked this same type of question 4 years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932829/run-a-script-to-rename-several-words-in-a-txt-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without utilising another tool/language, batch file solutions will generally write a new destination file before deleting the target file and performing a rename.

Here therefore is an option utilising the built-in `PowerShell` scripting language:

---

From a batch file, *with the text files in the current working directory*:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem '.\*.txt'|%%{(Get-Content $_.FullName) -CReplace 'EDI','INO'|Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

---

From the Command prompt, *with the text files in the current working directory*:

```bat
PowerShell -NoL -NoP "GCI '.\*.txt'|%{(GC $_.FullName) -CReplace 'EDI','INO'|SC $_.FullName}"
```

---

*If both cases, if you wish for the search string to be case insensitive, change `-CReplace` to `-Replace`*

Comment: Reading and writing the same file in one pipeline seems risky. This probably works because `Get-Content` reads the entire file. Because of that, it may not work well if the files are large.

Comment: I understand your concerns, @lit, however I've never had an issue arise from doing so. TBF, if the files are 'large', reading each line one by one within a standard batch file `for` loop, performing a replacement to a holding file, deleting or remaming the original file and renaming the holding file, doesn't sound particularly efficient. My answer was provided based on the title and question stipulation of saving to the 'same name' because the linked 'so called' duplicates all seem to be saving to different names. _I suppose they could save to the same name but in a different location though!_

Comment: I wish we had a `Run-Sed` cmdlet. How about `Run-Grep` and `Run-Awk` as well?

Comment: If the files were saved in a new directory on the same volume, deleting the existing directory and using the `MOVE` command would be very fast.

Comment: @lit, my concern with a 'large file', efficiency wise, was more the reading and writing one line at a time. However, I'm sure somebody will come along soon and suggest the OP pops along to DosTips and downloads/unzips a 100KB+ hybrid `.js`/`.bat` file containing well over 2000 lines of code, _of which half will be the usage information to read and digest_, and run that with the appropriate options!

Comment: PowerShell can process large files. Processing them efficiently is not as simple as `GC|SC`. I know what you mean about DosTips files. Their redemption is in the fact that often they do work.